# What's in this 524MB drive?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my dual boot PC with Windows 8.1. On Ubuntu I have seen a 524 MB drive popped up.[image: Drive Location]

As I take a look at it, its not swap or anything. Its contents are as follows: [Drive Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3lQ6.png)

Can I delete the partition and extend the 104 GB partition? Or I should leave it as it is?

Answer (score 1):

This is your EFI or UEFI partition.

It is used by systems that understands UEFI.

It contains the boot loader for Ubuntu and Windows 8 in your case.  Otherwise, it contains boot loaders for OS's installed on a machine.  I have the same partition, see image below.

[image]

Comment: My computer didn't have windows 8 pre-installed. Should UEFI be there?

Comment: Yes.  In my case I don't even have windows, and the partition is there.