# Why does System Monitor show two hard drives instead of one?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, uefi

I had to reinstall Ubuntu twice; is it possible there is still some left behind data? I only have one hard drive, but System Monitor shows as if I have 2? What's with the second one?

[image: System Monitor showing both / and /boot/efi]

Comment: Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/489491/whats-in-this-524mb-drive/489612#489612

Comment: ahh thank you so much! so its normal? and don't mess with it right?

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: It's normal, bro. The second is EFI's partition, don't worry, just don't touch it. Saludos :D